# ConfirmPrompt won't change yes or no by the localization given

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I'm trying to change the localization of my bot to change the yes and no response when I use the ConfirmPrompt. I tried to change the localization inside the activity but nothing change and it's just prompt the yes and no as normal.
So here's my code:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ConfirmStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    var bookingDetails = (BookingDetails)stepContext.Options;
    bookingDetails.TravelDate = (string)stepContext.Result;
    var messageText = $"Please confirm, I have you traveling to: {bookingDetails.Destination} from: {bookingDetails.Origin} on: {bookingDetails.TravelDate}. Is this correct?";
    var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
    stepContext.Context.Activity.Locale = "fr-BE";

    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ConfirmPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
}
```

I'm a newbie in Bot and I Don't know how it can be change to work for other language.

Comment: Do you consider my answer sufficient? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"fr-BE" isn't fully supported, currently. You can see the supported languages [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/blob/master/.NET/Microsoft.Recognizers.Text/Culture.cs).

Now, the real reason that locale isn't working in your example is that you're setting it manually with:

```cs
stepContext.Context.Activity.Locale = "fr-BE";
```

...and this doesn't get applied to `ConfirmPrompt`. Instead, you need the **client** to set the locale. It's different for every client, but for WebChat, you'd use something like:

```js
window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            token: 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_TOKEN'
        }),
        locale: 'fr-FR', // CHANGE ME
    },
    document.getElementById('webchat')
    );
```

For Emulator, you set the locale in Settings:

[image]

---

Also note that ConfirmPrompt [has a `DefaultLocale`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Prompts/ConfirmPrompt.cs#L51) setting that makes it so that if locale is not supplied at all on an activity, it defaults to whatever you set. WebChat and Emulator both will set `en-US` by default, therefore `ConfirmPrompt.DefaultLocale` will not work with WebChat/Emulator.

Comment: Web Chat supports `fr-FR`, but it does not support `fr-BR`. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/packages/component/src/Localization) are the locales that Web Chat supports.

Comment: Hello, I found a bug inside the bot framework code and that's why it's not working. If you want to know more information, here's the pull request I made: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/pull/2538

Comment: Good find! I should've mentioned we've already got a [PR in place that addresses this.](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/pull/2463)